# Identify this (transistor?)

Tags: transistors

I'm organising some components to get back into making (mostly blinking LEDs) exciting electronics, the usual BC547 etc are easy to google but I can't see anything on this .. What does it do?

[image: Cant find datasheet on this]

Answer (score 2):

[ST Micro STX826](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00071184.pdf) Low voltage PNP transistor

Comment: Not so difficult to Google as it turns out.

Comment: I never tried the ST bit :) just going on what's written on there. noted for future, tyvm!!

Comment: ST *is* written on there. It's the manufacturers name, and logo. Often highly helpful for figuring these things out if you can decipher what the logo is, so you are searching the right manufacturer's parts...